# Runtime Error in online Judge

Tags: java, file-io

I am coding a simple problem wherein I just have to sum the two numbers in a line of input file and in the output file the result of the sum of two numbers has to be printed.

The sample input is following :-

```
5                          //The first line is the number of test cases
22 12
23 12
1 1
2 3
100 100
```

Sample output is as follows

```
 34
 35
 2
 5
 200
```

Here is how I am doing it :-

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Test131009 {
   public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{

      Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
      PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File("main.out"));

     int T = in.nextInt();

     for(int t = 1; t <= T; t++) {
        int first = in.nextInt();
        int second = in.nextInt();
        int result = first + second;
        out.println(result);
     }
     out.close();
  }
}
```

I am not able to figure out why there is a runtime error as adjudged by the judge.

Comment: What's the stack trace of the error?

Comment: Can I get the stacktrace from an online judge? I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Run the code to get a stack trace.

Comment: When I ran it on the Sample input I got correct Sample Output

Comment: I'm not sure if you can get a stacktrace from an online judge. I guess it depends on the judge. Are your files accessible to your code when you run it there? Try putting a try-catch around your code, and either output the exception or write it to a file.

Comment: Is this USACO? Are you reading from the correct file?

Comment: No this one is from ahmed-aly.com. I think I have found it. I am not not supposed to read from any File but just from the System.in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked for me. I just needed to change taking the input from a File to System.in and writing output to System.out

Here is the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{

     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int T = in.nextInt();

    for(int t = 1; t <= T; t++) {
      int first = in.nextInt();
       int second = in.nextInt();
       int result = first + second;
       System.out.println(result);
    }

 }
}
```